# Python module cv2 is not available after "sudo apt-get install python-opencv"

Tags: python

I want to dabble with qr codes in Python.

pip3 install opencv-python fails on "skbuild". I read the FAQ [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), but pip3 will not upgrade itself. That fails with a long list of red text.

From the FAQ:

> Q: Pip install fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'skbuild'?
>
> Since opencv-python version 4.3.0.*, manylinux1 wheels were replaced
> by manylinux2014 wheels. If your pip is too old, it will try to use
> the new source distribution introduced in 4.3.0.38 to manually build
> OpenCV because it does not know how to install manylinux2014 wheels.
> However, source build will also fail because of too old pip because it
> does not understand build dependencies in pyproject.toml. To use the
> new manylinux2014 pre-built wheels (or to build from source), **your pip
> version must be >= 19.3**. Please upgrade pip with pip install --upgrade
> pip.

I have this version of pip:

> pedro@pedro-512ssd:~$ pip3 --version pip 9.0.1 from
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6) pedro@pedro-512ssd:~$

I saw on another [webpage](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) that I could get prebuilt binaries:

> sudo apt-get install python-opencv

I did this, no errors, but the Python module cv2 is still not available. In Idle I see:

> > > > import cv2 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
> > > > import cv2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

I rebooted, just in case that was necessary, but cv2 is still not available.

How can I get the Python module cv2 up and running??

Normally, I can get any module with a quick pip3 install the-Module-I-want.

Comment: Not clear if you want the Py2 or Py3 module. Your used pip3, but you told apt to install `python-opencv` instead of `python3-opencv`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! I use Python3, the old version is being phased out I heard.